# Multiple dynamic subdomains with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a database full of content pages, and I want to make 'pretty/dynamic' sub-domain links for it.

Example URL:

```
http://domain.com/?foo=foo&bar=bar
```

Example sub-domain (this should be the URL):

```
http://foo.bar.domain.com/
```

I think this should be possible with htaccess, but I'm not sure. I've tried a couple of things, with no luck... Is this possible at all? And if so, can somebody please show me how to setup my htaccess?

Comment: Can you provide us what you have tried in your htaccess file? If you have a specific issue with implementing it, we can help with that.

Comment: Do you have a wildcard DNS entry setup so `http://anything.anything.domain.com/` resolves to your host?

Comment: Yes, I have a wildcard setup in place. I don't have any solid examples though...

Answer (score 0):

If that work with DNS, you can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1?foo=%1&bar=%2 [L]
```